# GIMP not launching

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gimp

It was working fine, but stopped launching the next time after I changed the theme. When I try launching through the terminal, there is no response at all.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 OS (GIMP 2.8). I tried reinstalling the whole package, still there's no change.

I also tried the answers in these posts:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/732427/gimp-does-not-open-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `themerc` file in your Gimp profile (`~/.gimp-2.8/themerc`) and if this is not sufficient rename the whole Gimp profile (`~/.gimp-2.8` to `~/.gimp-2.8.disabled` for instance) so that Gimp recreates a new one. Once Gimp starts normally, you can then copy things back from the old profile.

PS: Note the leading dot in the Gimp profile name, which means you don't see it by default.

Comment: And we would like to know what exactly caused this - so if it was the themerc, please elaborate on what theme you have used, and please make the themerc available somewhere.